# Intellisense not working with scipy.optimize.curve_fit

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Intellisense for python is normally working for me without any issue. However, the following code makes it unresponsive. In particular, as soon as I open the file containing this code in VScode, the Intellisense stops working altogether until I restart VScode. I have not been able to find any error message corresponding to opening of this particular file. Can you spot the issue?

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def gaus(x,a,x0,sigma):
    return a*np.exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigma**2))

nbins = 50
xmax = 30
noise = np.random.normal(10, 1, 1000)
plt.figure("noise")
hist,bin_edges,_ = plt.hist(noise,range=(0,xmax), bins=nbins, \
    label=f"Mean: {np.mean(noise):5.1f} e$^-$\nRMS:  {np.std(noise):5.1f} e$^-$")
bin_mid = (bin_edges[:-1] + bin_edges[1:])/2
popt,pcov = curve_fit(gaus, bin_mid, hist, [10,np.mean(noise),np.std(noise)])
plt.plot(np.arange(0,xmax,xmax/nbins/10),gaus(np.arange(0,xmax,xmax/nbins/10),*popt), \
    label=f'$\mu$:    {popt[1]:5.1f} e$^-$\n$\sigma$:    {popt[2]:5.1f} e$^-$')
plt.legend(loc="upper right", prop={"family":"monospace"})
plt.xlim(0,xmax)
plt.show()
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Issue followed here: https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/1890
Current workaround:
> you can disable the python.analysis.useLibraryCodeForTypes. This will avoid the long analysis times, but it will also mean that completion suggestions will not be available for symbols that come from untyped libraries.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in Pylance version 2021.10.0, which was just released. You can find the changelog here: https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#2021100-6-october-2021